# How to use Angularjs inline conditional in this example?

Tags: angularjs

For the code below, is there anyway in angular to include an inline conditional to only show schedules in the ng-repeater with schedules, if {{schedules.position}} = {{position.position}}   ?

```
          .positions(ng-repeat='position in positions')
            .row
              {{position}}
              .row
              .col-sm-4.col-md-4
              .col-sm-8.col-md-8
                .schedule(ng-repeat='schedule in schedules')
                  .row
                    .col-sm-1.col-md-1.
                      %input(ng-model = "string" type = 'checkbox')
                    .col-sm-7.col-md-7.
                      %table
                        %tr
                          %td
                           {{schedule.first_name}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...just remove the `{{}}` and use a comparison operator

```
<div ng-if="schedules.position == position.position">
```

Let you convert from html as I'm not familiar with your templating syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide), [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to your scope that filters for you.

```
$scope.filterSchedule = function(pos) { 
    return _.filter(schedules, function(sch) { 
        return sch.position == pos; });
    }
```

Then your inner repeat could be

```
ng-repeat="schedule in filterSchedule(position)"
```